Bash Script Fails to Find and Update Specific Line with `grep` and `sed`
I'm writing a simple script to add Wayland support options to specific application files. The script uses grep to check for a line, and sed to add options to it if the options are missing. However, I'm running into an issue where grep can't find the line I'm searching for, even though it exists in the file.
Here's the simplified script:
#!/bin/bash

update_wayland() {
    local app_name="$1"
    local file_path="$2"
    local current_line="$3"
    local additional_text="$4"

    if grep -Fq "${current_line} ${additional_text}" "$file_path"; then
        echo "[No Change] Wayland support is already enabled in $app_name."
        return 0
    fi

    if grep -Fq "$current_line" "$file_path"; then
        echo "[Update] Adding Wayland support to $app_name."
        sed -i "s|$current_line|$current_line $additional_text|" "$file_path"
    else
        echo "[Error] Specified line not found in $app_name."
    fi
}

update_wayland "spotify" \
    "/usr/bin/spotify" \
    'exec /opt/spotify/spotify "${SPOTIFY_USER_FLAGS[@]}" "$@"' \
    "--enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland"


Contents of /usr/bin/spotify:
#!/bin/bash
exec /opt/spotify/spotify "${SPOTIFY_USER_FLAGS[@]}" "$@"

Expected Behavior:
The script should match the line exec /opt/spotify/spotify "${SPOTIFY_USER_FLAGS[@]}" "$@" in /usr/bin/spotify and add the Wayland options to it if they are missing.
Actual Behavior:
The script returns `[Error] Specified line not found

Using grep -F makes it possible to specify a fixed string instead of a regular expression. No such option exists for sed, though, so sed uses the string as a regular expression, and fails: becuase $ and [@] have special meaning in regular expressions.
The following works for me:

Remove the -F from both calls to grep.
Use the following expression as the 3rd parameter to update_wayland:

'exec /opt/spotify/spotify "\${SPOTIFY_USER_FLAGS\[@\]}" "\$@"'


See "Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed" (and especially the accepted answer).
